# Server software with ftp access, web file access, email links to files with expiry, and dual custom interface for a digital agency

Tags: ftp, web

I'm looking for web based ftp software with the following features

1. Simple web based interface for admin
2. Users are synced for normal ftp access and web access
3. Segregation into client areas
4. Email link to file with expire timing
5. Way to create a front end login page, that will just show a list of files that can be downloaded. Easy to style

I really like ajaxplorer, but it doesn't seem to have 2,4 or 5.

For 2, I could use the http://www.ajaxplorer.info/wordpress/plugins/auth/ftp/ plugin and manage it on the ftp side, but would be nicer to do it from the web side.

for 4, I would have to write a custom plugin to do this I guess

for 5, I would have to create a custom skin, using the mobile plugin skin as a starting point.

Does anyone have any advice about how I could do this easier, paid for or otherwise.

EDIT:

I am currently testing CrushFTP and will report back here if it meets all the requirements.

Comment: I am currently testing CrushFTP and will report back here if it meets all the requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something hosted or something you install on your own web server?

There are loads of hosted services out there for this.  ShareFile.com comes to mind.  They have plans that include most of the features you mention above...not sure about #5 though...you'd have to look into what they offer.  Google "send large files" and you'll get pages full of similar services.

Sharefile.com allows you to access files via the web interface or a standard FTP client.  You can setup users with various permissions/groups and they have a fairly simple interface for admin and regular users.

As I mentioned, there are lots of these services, Sharefile is just the one I'm most familiar with.

Comment: Looking for something hosted, as 5 is an important requirement, and could be a large amount of data (100GB+) so is cheaper to run on own server.

5 is so that this same software can be embeded into the main clients website, without redirecting to a new site. (I'm thinking iframe)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at FileCatalyst Webmail, it seems to answer all your requirements.

It is not a hosted service but rather a software solution (you deploy it on your own hardware)

It offers a solution for large email attachments and online drop box (file area)

It also can be branded by making your own skin.

http://www.filecatalyst.com/products/filecatalyst-webmail/

Answer (score -1):

I'm a bit confused.  Most web browsers support FTP directly, if you type ftp://ftp.mozilla.org into your web browser, it connects to the target FTP server and lets you download files.

Is that what you need?

If so, assuming you have a server somewhere running an FTP server, you might want to use something like [webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) to allow you to manage that FTP server using a graphical interface, but that's nothing to do with users downloading files, or web access.

It looks to me like you have confused requirements.  You need a web server, and an ftp server, and then users with a standard web browser can connect to the web server to see a front page, and it can provide FTP links so they can download stuff.  But, people could also use a standard FTP client to connect to the FTP server.  You then need to install something like [webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) to provide a graphical front end to managing that web and ftp server.

If you don't really need FTP and are just using that to mean 'file transfer' then you probably want some kind of web based content management system which supports expiring links to files (usually related to web commerce systems which I guess is what you're getting at).

Comment: Hi, no I am definitely sure of my requirements and that is whats needed. It's for sending and management of large client files within a post production agency.

Comment: 'Web based ftp' doesn't make any sense, sorry.

Comment: Sorry yes, that is not clear, I'll edit the title.